# linux: supervisor net-snmp mibs

Tags: python-3.x, supervisord, net-snmp

I'm setting up a Flask RESTapi for NET-SNMP because i'm doing most development in Windows.

The problem is that Supervisor does not find my installed mibs.
Everything works if i run the flask app manually with Gunicorn.

But with supervisor i get exceptions saying it cannot locate mibs-files.

Installed mibs are in /home/web/.snmp

supervisor conf

```
[program:app]
command = /home/web/www/venv/bin/python3.6 /home/web/www/venv/bin/gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000
directory = /home/web/www/app
user = web
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

added environment to the config

```
[program:app]
command = /home/web/www/venv/bin/python3.6 /home/web/www/venv/bin/gunicorn 
app:app -b localhost:8000
directory = /home/web/www/app
user = web
environment=HOME="/home/web",USER="web"
```